# Has anyone ever (beautifully!) escaped check with checkmate?

Tags: checkmate, check

I was wondering if this beautiful situation has ever happened in a real-life game, especially in a competition.

**Has anyone ever escaped check with checkmate? That is: has anyone ever, after being checked, decided to checkmate instead of running with the king?** If yes, who, when, in what tournament, in what position?

If you are thinking this is impossible, you are wrong! I created this beautiful example (that relies on a blunder by Black, but is still the most beautiful move sequence I've ever seen):

```
[FEN "3rkr2/4q3/7Q/8/8/1B5K/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. Ba4+ Qd7+?? 2. Qe6#
```

I had never seen check-check-checkmate like this before.

Of course, in this example, black is winning, and has better options than Qd7+, but I am sure a more complicated position can be arranged in which black is in a lost position anyway.

Comment: You are right, I am sorry, I will search more before asking, from now on.

Comment: Is it beautiful?